# Passing a value from a combobox, populated from an ObservableCollection into another method UWP

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp, observablecollection

I have a combobox in my main page.xmal, it is populated from an ObservableCollection and displays a list of Country Names. What I want to happen is, When the user selects the name of the country, I want to pass a code which is assoicated with each country. The Name and the Code are both stored in the ObservableCollection.

I presume I can set a property in the combobox which allow me too, set the selected item equal to the country code. Any help would be great.

```
     <StackPanel Margin="10,100,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" >
        <ComboBox Name="countryCombo"
            PlaceholderText="Select Country"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ReadInFile.CountryCodes, Mode=OneWay}" 
            SelectedIndex="{x:Bind ReadInFile.SelectedIndex}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            SelectedValuePath="Code"
            MinWidth="250" Margin="5" Opacity="0.65">
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox Name="CityTextBox" PlaceholderText="Enter City"/>
    </StackPanel>

 private async void WeatherCityButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs  e)
    {
        var city = CityTextBox.Text.ToString();
        var country = countryCombo.SelectedValuePath.ToString();

        RootObject myCityWeather = await WeatherFacade.GetWeatherCity(country, city);

        WeatherResultCityText.Text = myCityWeather.current_observation.display_location.city + " _  " + myCityWeather.current_observation.temp_c.ToString() + "-" + myCityWeather.current_observation.wind_kph;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got it set up how you want it - `SelectedValuePath` does precisely what you describe. Once that's set, accessing the ComboBox's `SelectedValue` property will provide the code for the selected item.

You need only to change this line:

```
var country = countryCombo.SelectedValuePath.ToString();
```

To:

```
var country = countryCombo.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

The way you had it simply will return "Code", if I'm not mistaken, as you're retrieving the same value you put in.

Comment: Great that worked a treat. Sometimes its hard to see the wood from the trees.

Comment: No problem - happens to everyone from time to time. Please mark it as an answer since it worked for you. :3